# Pytorch memory managing, CNN-LSTM model and FHD Video (out of memory problem)

Tags: python, memory, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm

I want to address this problem.
I made CNN-LSTM architecture using pytorch with `[(3, 1920, 1080), 60fps, 10sec]` video data.
CNN architecture is below.

[image: 1]

**1. Data split**

I separated 60fps video into 1 batch size(So, it has a total of 10 pieces) and tested the sample model with 2 batch sizes.

**2. Model training**

The training code is below

```
def train(dataloader, cnn_model, lstm_model, loss_fn, optimizer):

    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):

        cnn_results = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE,FPS*SEC,CNN_OUTPUT, device=device)

        # CNN forward
        for idx, batch in enumerate(X):
            batch = batch.type(torch.FloatTensor).to(device).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
            cnn_result = cnn_model(batch)
            cnn_results[idx] = cnn_result

        # LSTM forward
        lstm_results = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE, 3, device=device)
        for idx, result in enumerate(cnn_results):
            (lstm_hidden, lstm_cell) = lstm_model.module.initLSTM()
            l_output, (lstm_hidden, lstm_cell) = lstm_model(result.unsqueeze(0), lstm_hidden, lstm_cell)
            lstm_results[idx] = l_output[-1]
        y = y.to(device)
        loss = criterion(lstm_results, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(loss)

loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
epochs = 5
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(train_loader, model, lstm, loss_fn, optimizer)
print("Done!")
```

At first, 60fps image is processed by CNN. And those are stored in a torch.zero containers(Size: batch_size,60,64).

Those things are used for the LSTM's input. The final output is (batch_size, 3)

**3. Hardware**

I use 2080 ti super GPU * 8, So total GPU memory is 11019MiB * 8

**Question**

I really don't know why torch says "Out of memory".
I think it's enough to process my video data.
I guess one thing is that memory is stored every epoch, because of my code.

Addition1 - nvidia-smi image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YuJV.png)

Addition2 - model parameter compare

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrn0F.png) \n
2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXJul.png)

Comment: I'd be surprised if this 11GB GPU could fit 60*10 full HD images, even for a very small CNN (which is not the case). The total GPU memory is 11GB, unless some model parallelism is hidden in there. OOM seems to be reasonable here.

Comment: I use a Parallel model, and the total GPU memory is around 80GB.
And I still wonder that it's too hard for my GPU to use FHD Video in my model?
I checked the amount used of GPU, and it used 58,414MiB in 1 batch size.

Comment: Yes, the video is still too long to fit, IMO. To help you, you'd have to share how you implemented your model parallelism. Also, share the complete traceback and the specific input shape for batch_size=1.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment, I prepared some data.
Actually, I don't understand about model parallelism. Is it setting of training? If it is right, the code is bellow.
---------------------
model = CNN().to(device);
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model);
model.cuda();
lstm = LSTM(32).to(device);
lstm = torch.nn.DataParallel(lstm);
lstm.cuda();

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss();
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01);
--------------
I just use normal setting of pytorch.

Comment: And the input shape is (batch_size, total_frame, 1280, 720, 3).
I checked the limit size of total_frame. 120frame was ok, but 150 frame made out of memory.

Comment: This is "data parallelism", not model parallelism. In this case, your entire model has to fit in a single GPU (it will be replicated in the others), i.e., your memory limit is 11GB.

Comment: I didn't know difference data parallelism and model parallelism. I didn't make my model parallel. But, I upload my GPU memory table. Isn't it using all GPU memory?

Comment: It uses, but not in the way you think. As I said, it splits the batch and replicates the model in the other GPUs. Therefore, the entire model still has to fit in a single GPU, otherwise OOM.

Comment: I conducted a test that compare large parameter model and small parameter model in 854x480 size image.
But I think it is something wrong. 
because small parameter model has large total memory size. 
I uploaded that result. Model 1 has 116,337,728 params but, it needs only 820.73MB. Model 2 has 8,179,064 params but, it needs 3424.07 MB(Actually Model 2 is Efficientnet-b0 model). Is there other knowles that I don't know?

Comment: Less parameters will not necessarily result in less memory. What takes most of the memory during training are the activation maps, not the parameters themselves.